# MySql Unknown column in where

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I am a beginner and try to have a very simple messaging system.
every thing is managed via the ID's of the users..

So if someone types the username of a person i have to convert it into the person's id:

```
$res_name = $_POST["res_name"];
    $res_id = userToId($res_name);
```

This function looks like this:

```
function userToId($username) {
    $data = array();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();

    if($func_num_args = 1)
    {
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `z_network_users` WHERE `username` = `$username`") or die(mysql_error());
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    }
    return $data['id'];
}
```

it doesn't work, in fact it can't find a username even if it's existing..

the error is for example:

> Unknown column 'testperson' in 'where clause'

the user exists, hope you can help me :)
ps: I know I shouldn't use mysql_* but i haven' learned the better version.. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using backticks around your variable then it will be considered as column

thats why you got that error `Unknown column 'testperson' in 'where clause'`

you should use this  (you should escape your variable to prevent sql injection)

```
 $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
 $res = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `z_network_users` 
        WHERE `username` = '$username' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

or this

```
 $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
 $res = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `z_network_users` 
        WHERE `username` = '".$username."' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

try that function:

```
 function userToId($username) {

   $func_get_args = func_get_args();
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
   if($func_num_args == 1)
{
   $res = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `z_network_users` WHERE `username` = '$username' ") or die(mysql_error());
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

}
  return $row['id'];
}
```

Comment: it does! that's why I love stack overflow :)

Comment: stackoverflow should give you 10000 reputation just for this love :).

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `around your`value` I think.

Comment: Yes, really. And you should escape values. SQL injection etc.

Comment: Yes you should not use.

Comment: This answer makes no sense as is. A backtick is a special markup character here.

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT id FROM `z_network_users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"
```

this will fix your query BUT mysql_* functions are deprecated, so you should avoid using them. Try mysqli or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be backticking the entries

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `z_network_users` WHERE `username` = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

You only quote *column names* with backticks.

```
WHERE `username` = `$username`
```

This makes `$username` into a column name. You want a string instead:

```
WHERE `username` = '$username'
```

Also definitely see [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Answer (score 0):

you have not any column but

```
WHERE `username` = `$username`"
```

but `$username` understanding as a column so remove `` from $username and put single quote to it like '$username'

Answer (score 0):

I think your query return more then 1. you need to use `mysql_num_rows()` to get one record. Thats why it doesn't work.

Comment: no there is just one value, but i got it :) thanks for your answer!

Comment: ' $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
 $res = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `z_network_users` 
        WHERE `username` = '".$username."' ") or die(mysql_error());' this worked :) thanks to @echo_me